# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 80 Error comes when sending emails

Tags: c#, sql-server, email, exception

I am developing a simple alert system. There are alerts in a SQL table (collected by an **INNER JOIN**)with the ***user*** to be sent, ***email*** address and some other information. What I want to do is, read the table and send the alert messages to the relevant email addresses.
I developed an application for that, with a for loop. But at the end of the process there is an exception occurs. 
There are 80 rows in the table(80 is dynamic. It can change time to time). ***For*** loop begins with 0 in index and it retrieves the 1st item in the table and continues without any error in between. But, after sending the 80th alert (Last alert) it shows an exception as

> "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at position 80" .

I do not know how to fix this. I tried in many ways but could not resolve this problem. Is there any one out there who can help me with this issue?.

```
   Common ComMsg = new Common();//Common is a name of a class
   DataSet DatMsg = new DataSet();
   private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DatMsg = ComMsg.ReturnDataSet("SELECT RptAlertRecipient.Name,  RptAlertRecipient.Email,  RptAlerts.Factory,  RptAlerts.AlertTime,  RptAlerts.Description " +
                                      "FROM RptAlerts " +
                                      "INNER JOIN RptAlertTypes ON  RptAlerts.AlertTypeID = RptAlertTypes.ID " +
                                      "INNER JOIN RptAlertType_RecipientMapping ON  RptAlertTypes.ID = RptAlertType_RecipientMapping.AlertTypeID " +
                                      "INNER JOIN RptAlertRecipient ON  RptAlertType_RecipientMapping.AlertRecipientID = RptAlertRecipient.ID " +
                                      "ORDER BY RptAlertRecipient.Name ASC");

            for (int i = 0; i < DatMsg.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (DatMsg.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    string to = DatMsg.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    string from = "from_mail_address@mydomain.com";
                    string subject = "Alert In Time";
                    string msgBody = "Dear " + DatMsg.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString() + "," + "<br/>" + "<br/>" + DatMsg.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString() + "<br/>" + "<br/>" + "Regards" + "<br/>" + "Sent by Alert Service";
                    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, msgBody);
                    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    SmtpClient clnt = new SmtpClient("mail.smtpserveraddress.local", 25);
                    clnt.EnableSsl = false;
                    clnt.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("from_mail_address@mydomain.com", "password");
                    clnt.Send(msg);
                }  
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Message.Show("Error: "+ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can any of the columns you are using be null?

Comment: No. All the columns are filled with some information.

Comment: Which line throws row index out-of-range error? The `for` loop seems to be correct, but somewhere inside the loop went wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is with your for loop. It should be as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DatMsg.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    ....
}
```

As index starts with 0 the 80th item will be at position 79

Comment: The original was correct. Your version will end up at index 78

Comment: If the start index is 0 then how can 80th item be at 78? its is on 79th

Comment: Yes, but in your for loop the `i` will  go from 0-78

Comment: No, there are 80 rows
So DatMsg.Tables[0].Rows.Count = 80
So DatMsg.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1 = 79

That is why loop will run from 0 to 79 = 80 elements

Comment: look at the condition... `i < DatMsg...` - it says less than - meaning it won't get to 79